# How to get image URL after uploaded in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, image, url, upload, media

I upload some images to Media Library (not in post) and want to get URLs (image's full path) after the uploading process is finished. Is there any solution or plugin to do that job?

Example: I upload 20 images to Media Library, right after the process is completed, a list URLs of 20 images appears on the screen so I can copy all the URLs instead of getting URL on each image, it takes many times.

Comment: You need to elaborate on thecontext of where and what you want with the URLS .

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're doing some sort of programming using PHP and want to have something better than just inspecting the element and hard-coding that in, you can use the WordPress function `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`.

Check out the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) for proper usage.

Answer (score 1):

From inside your WordPress dashboard, click Media > Library.

On the next screen, hover your mouse over the image you want the link for, and click the Edit link that shows up (or just click the title of the image).

On the right hand side, there should be a spot that shows the file URL.

I believe this is what you were looking for, if not, please clarify.

Comment: Example: I upload 20 images to Media Library, right after the process is completed, a list URLs of 20 images appears on the screen so I can copy all the URLs instead of getting URL on each image, it takes many times.